# Spring boot unit test with h2 failing for schema

Tags: spring-boot, junit, h2

I have sql file with insert statements like below

> insert into demo.course (col1, col2) VALUES( 'Val 1', 'KS1')

My unit test

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@DataJpaTest
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase //h2
@ActiveProfiles("test")
class TopicRepositoryTest extends BaseRepositoryTest {

    @Test
    public void newTopicCreationShouldBePossible() {        
        Topics newTopic = createTopics("STEAM"); //from base
        assertNotNull(newTopic.getId());
    }
}
```

Application-test.props

> spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;IGNORECASE=TRUE;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;DATABASE_TO_UPPER=false
>
> spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema=DEMO
>
> spring.datasource.hikari.schema=DEMO

Error:

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
> Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class
> path resource
> [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]:
> Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is
> org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException:
> Failed to execute SQL script statement #1 of class path resource
> [maria/importcommon.sql]: insert into demo.mytable (col1, col2)
> VALUES( 'Val 1', 'KS1'); nested exception is
> org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Schema "DEMO" not found; SQL
> statement:

Reading some posts , I added the below, but it is not working

> spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema=DEMO
>
> spring.datasource.hikari.schema=DEMO

How can I fix this issue and pass my tests?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to update your insert statements without schema prefix

> insert into course (col1, col2) VALUES( 'Val 1', 'KS1');

removed "demo."

Comment: I see an error - Schema not found sql statement. The app.property spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema=demo is interfereing with application-test.properties. So is there a way to make that schema none?

Comment: works if I dont specify empty in test profile properties spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema=